# I can't change the hinttext in the dropdownButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton

This is my code, and i dont know why the hint doesnt change, when i click the options, obviously all this code is inside a class, I tried to use a for loop to identify the list positions , and if they were right, it would appear on the screen.

```
final listgenre = ["Masc", "Fem", "Não Binário"];
var listgenre_value;
String newValue = "";
var valueChoose;
String hintValue = "";
   Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 10, right: 15),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                      hint: Text("Genero :$hintValue"),
                      dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                      iconSize: 36,
                      iconEnabledColor: Colors.black,
                      isExpanded: true,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black),
                      value: valueChoose,
                      underline: SizedBox(
                        width: 320,
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                      items: listgenre.map((valueitem) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: valueitem,
                          child: Text(valueitem),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          for (int i = 0; i <= listgenre.length; i++) {
                            if (listgenre[i] != newValue) {
                              listgenre_value = i + 1;
                            } else {
                              hintValue = "$newValue";
                              // ignore: void_checks
                              return listgenre_value;
                            }
                          }

                          Object? valueChoose = newValue;
                          String valueChoosen = valueChoose.toString();
                        });
                      },
                    ))),
```

Comment: What is your expected output? I ran the above code and [this](https://i.ibb.co/XDWzc52/Flutter.jpg) is what I got.

Comment: Well, i really expected that output, but on my phone the "Masc" part just doesnt appear.
Thanks for the help.
Did u change anything in the code?

Comment: Not really. Did you try running it on multiple emulators?

Comment: No, actually because my visual studio cant run any of those(with the android emulators), and i tried that a lot of times, every and each time i run my app it's on my real phone. an LM X540

Comment: Does it work with the solution now? Because it is the only issue I think is causing the undesired output.

Comment: Yes, it worked, just putting my variables and arrays declared before "Widget Build" , thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments, the ***same*** code doesn't give the expected output.

It is only possible if you are also initialising the variables ***inside*** the build method, which shouldn't be the case.

### Incorrect Code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    // ---- your variables INSIDE build method

    final listgenre = ["Masc", "Fem", "Não Binário"];
    var listgenre_value;
    String newValue = "";
    var valueChoose;
    String hintValue = "";

// ------- rest of the code continued
```

### Correct Code

```
  final listgenre = ["Masc", "Fem", "Não Binário"];
  var listgenre_value;
  String newValue = "";
  var valueChoose;
  String hintValue = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  // ------- rest of the code continued
```

As the `build` method is called every time `setState` is called, `hintValue` was being initialised to `""` i.e empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to fix this error is **abdev**'s comment. It will help if you put the variables used by the `DropdownButton` widget above the `build` method.
I hope it was helpful!